# Rename files matching expression

Tags: scripts, regex, batch-rename

I have to rename a lot of jpg files like Portrait_14-9-100390.jpg to Portrait-9-100390.jpg,i.e. remove _nn part.
I did that with a dumb shell script :

`sudo rename -f -v 's/_20//' /var/www/prod/110253/110253-IND/*.jpg`

with lines for 20 to 1.
It does the job but I'm pretty sure there is a means to do that with one or two lines.
I don't know regex at all, could somebody help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rename` command on current Ubuntu distributions uses Perl expressions.

You can match a single decimal digit in a Perl regular expression using `\d`. So `\d+` for a sequence of one or more decimal digits, or `\d{1,2}` for one or two digits, ex. `s/_\d{1,2}//`

Note that the above would match the `_12` in `_123` and turn it into `_3` - if you only want to match *exactly* 1 or 2 digits after the underscore then you could add a *negative lookahead*, like `s/_\d{1,2}(?!\d)//`

See [perlre: Character Classes and other Special Escapes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Character-Classes-and-other-Special-Escapes)

---

Alternatively, you could use a KSH-style extended glob pattern to match one or more digits as `+([0-9])`, allowing you to perform the renaming with a simple bash shell loop:

```
shopt -s extglob

for f in *_+([0-9])*; do 
  echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f/_+([0-9])/}"
done
```

(remove the `echo` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing).

Extended globs don't have Perl-style lookarounds so if you need to exclude longer digit sequences you'd need to do something like `*_[0-9]@(|[0-9])[^0-9]*` which is not quite the same (matching a following non-digit instead of not matching a following digit).

In zsh, you have the option to use numeric ranges in glob expressions, so for example

```
autoload -Uz zmv

zmv -n  '*(_<1-20>)*' '${f/$1/}'
```

The documentation for `zmv` may be found in `man zshcontrib`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

Name: renamefiles

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern="_[0-9]{1,2}"

for x in *
do
echo $x | grep -Eq $pattern
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
rmnum=$(echo $x | grep -oE $pattern)
mv -n $x $(echo $x | tr -d $rmnum);
fi
done
```

to execute it you need to provide appropriate permissions

```
sudo chown {yourUsername} renamefiles
sudo chmod u+x renamefiles
```

and finally execute it

```
./renamefiles
```